# maven clean install still loads old version of dependency when updating parent pom file

Tags: maven

I am using Maven for building my code. I created module based maven structure like below:

```
Parent POM
   Child POM
```

Parent POM:

```
<project ..>  

  <groupId>the.company.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>Parent-POM</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  ...

  <properties>
     <module.version>1.0</module.version>
  </properties>

</project>
```

Child POM:

```
<project ..>  

  <groupId>the.company.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>Child-POM</artifactId>
  <version>${module.version}</version>
  ...

</project>
```

When I update the module version from `1.0` to `2.0` in Parent POM, and I run command `mvn clean install -Ponline -Dmaven.test.skip=true`, I find it still compiles the `1.0` version of module. However, when I run the mvn command again, I find it starts to use the new `2.0` version, I wonder if there is any cache for mvn?

Comment: This is an FAQ. You cannot use a property like this to specify a project version. Up until Maven 3.5.0 the version tag must specify an actual version value. Maven 3.5.0 introduced the ability to use the special properties "${revision}, ${sha1} and/or ${changelist}" which provide support for CI. See [Maven CI Friendly Versions](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html)

Comment: Does the child pom contain a `<parent>..</parent>` entry?

Comment: No, the child pom doesn't contain `<parent>..</parent>` entry